# pushed code from a git submodule, but can't pull it again from the main working directory

Tags: git, push, pull, git-submodules

I have a project that pulls in a library as a submodule from a different repo.  I made a branch with some changes in the library from within the submodule directory and sucessfully pushed it to Github.  When I tried pulling the changes from within the library's main development, I get "Already up-to-date." when I know it's not.  I can clone the library's repo and there are my changes.  Why won't pull notice the changes?

Comment: When you pushed from the submodule, did you push to a new branch on Github? In your library's repo, what does `git fetch` say? Did any new branches appear?

Comment: I did push the new branch.  Everything comes across as expected if I do a fresh clone.  `git fetch` returned nothing.  No new branches appeared.

Comment: Somehow having my library project pushing to two repos (sourceforge and github) caused this odd behavior.  I commented out the extra url line from the [remote "origin"] section of .git/config and `git pull` did what I wanted.  Weird.  Any idea if this should be reported as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 separate remotes set up. One for sourceforge and one for github. You can then choose which you want to push to. As long as you don't call `git submodule init`, you can switch your submodule to point to the other repo and get changes from there when you like.